# How to pull Spanish letters from teradata?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, teradata

Here is the connection string

```
jdbc:teradata://DSN/LOGMECH=LDAP,tmode=TERA,charset=UTF8,RECONNECT_COUNT=11
```

**I specified  `UTF8` so everything should  work fine .**

Test query

```
SELECT 'test á é í ó ú ñ Ñ Á É Í Ó Ú test'  AS   test  
FROM tstTable2
```

---

Output the result in Java

```
resultSet.next(); 
String out = resultSet.getString (1); 
System.out.println(out);
```

get the following result

```
test    test
```

**So the Spanish character do not get printed 
Why?**

---

By the way . When I simply print without querying the   Teradata

```
System.out.println("test á é í ó ú ñ Ñ Á É Í Ó Ú test");
```

all characters print  fine , so I know it is the `getString` method that doesn't work